# Search for string in 2nd level keys of a 3d array; upon match, check if 1st level key equals specific string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements, filtering

```
$display_name = get_the_author_meta('display_name');

$config = array(
    'premium_users' => [
        'rahat' => [
            'color' => 'blue',
            'icon' => 'fa-check-circle'
        ],
        'jondoe' => [
            'color' => 'orange',
            'icon' => 'fa-check'
        ]
    ],
    'secondary_users' => [
        'smith' => [
            'color' => 'purple',
            'icon' => 'fa-check'
        ]
    ],
);


$verified_author = "";
foreach ($config as $group => $users) {
    foreach ($users as $author => $data) {

        if ($author === $display_name && $group === 'premium_users') {
            $verified = '<'.$wrap.' class="i-'.$data['icon'].' '.
            $data['color'].'"></'.$wrap.'>';
        echo    $verified_author;
            break;
        }

    }

if($group === 'premium_users') {
    echo $group;
}
```

I want to Echo all users list with premium_user if ['premium_users'] defined.

Please modify this function. Get value from config if defined [premium_user] then echo all users that have premium or secondary user.

Comment: i want to echo premium user list and secondary user list.

Comment: If the selected user is a premium user, do you want to list all users in premium and secondary subsets? or only list the premium users?  Your question is not clear on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the first level's elements and use the same lookup technique with `isset()`.

```
$verified = '';
foreach ($config as $level => $users) {
    if (isset($users[$display_name])) {
        $verified = sprintf(
            '<i class="%s %s"></i>',
            $users[$display_name]['icon'],
            $users[$display_name]['color']
        );
        if ($level === 'premium_users') {
            echo implode(', ', array_keys($config[$level])); // print premium names
        }                
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to look like this, 
if (isset($users[$username]) && isset($user['premium_users'])) {
 echo all premium users list;
}

Comment: please modify this, i want to echo all user if(isset['premium_users'])

Comment: Please clarify your code in your question via an edit.  Then everyone will understand what you need.

Comment: Sir, see now and please modify.

Comment: You aren't very expressive about your exact desired output.  You cannot `echo` an array.  I'll assume that you mean to `echo` the names/keys in the premium subset.

Answer (score 0):

Your user information is 2 levels deep into your config array and your foreach loop is checking level 1 of the array. Change your loop to this...

```php
foreach ($config as $group => $users) {
    foreach ($users as $user_name => $user_config) {
        if ($user_name === $display_name) {
            $verified = '<i class="'.$user_config['icon'].' '. $user_config['color'].'"></i>';
            echo $verified;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First code is original second is expecting.